# Missing parameter type error with Iterable Trait method in Scala.

Tags: scala, iterable

I can store the class type in an array and create the instance from it.

```
class A
val keys = Array[Class[_]](classOf[A])
keys(0).newInstance
> res130: Any = A@339319d
```

However, when I tried with Iterable Trait method, I get missing parameter type error.

```
keys.zipWithIndex { case (t, i) => t.newInstance }

error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[Class[_]],(?, Int),?]
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zipWithIndex` doesn't take arguments except for an implicit `CanBuildFrom`, which in your case is being replaced with your pattern match. It looks like what you're looking for is `map` or some other method to iterate over the elements. Try something like this:

```
  keys.zipWithIndex.map { case (t, i) => t.newInstance }
```

Comment: Or equivalently in this case, since the index is simply thrown away: `keys.map(_.newInstance)`.